# Userform doesnt close properly

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Original question:
I have a userform that opens, some info is entered, and has a cancel and OK button.  When i click cancel it unloads the userform and closes the window, then the blank window opens again?

Update:
I thought i just messed something up and copying and pasting all code into a new workbook would work.  It seemed to for some initial testing and now it is doing the same thing again.

I am guessing it has something to do with all the textbox_exit subs?

On main worksheet there is a format button that brings up userform1.  Some info is entered and the button options are Cancel and OK.  Cancel should just unload the userform1 and hide it.  OK goes on to userform3.  (userform2 was deleted and I never renamed them)

Userform3 more info is entered and there is Cancel and OK again.  OK should run the rest of the macro, and cancel should unload and hides userform3.

When i click either button on userform3 it unloads the form (expected) then the form closes and immediately userform1 re-opens (unexpected/unwanted)

when i click OK on userform1 Cancel userform1 unloads and disappears and then immediately re-opens (unloaded/blank) pops up?

Fixed, but still have questions.
As was mentioned in comments below this was copied to a new workbook and it seemed to fix itself.  Then for whatever reason it started doing the same thing again.  I left work on Friday and dint think twice about it.  Now on Monday it seems to be working?  Does anyone have any idea what might have caused the need for hitting cancel twice to get the form to disappear?

here is the code on userform1

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'centers the userform on the active excel screen
    Me.StartUpPosition = 0
    Me.Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * Me.Width)
    Me.top = Application.top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * Me.Height)


    Sheets("hidden").Range("A2:C2").Clear

End Sub
Private Sub Cancel_UserForm1_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub
Public Sub OK_UserForm1_Click()

    Dim chk As Control
    Dim c, i, j, k, m As Long

    'START DATE populated
    If TextBox1 = "" Then
                'SEQUENCE populated (get double error at same time rather than 2 individual errors)
                If TextBox2 = "" Then
                            'PROPNUM COLUMN populated (get triple error at same time)
                            If TextBox8 = "" Then
                                        'all 3 blank
                                        TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
                                        TextBox2.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
                                        TextBox8.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
                                        TextBox1.SetFocus
                                        MsgBox "Please enter start date, beginning sequence number, and propnum column"
                                        Exit Sub
                            Else
                                        'first 2 blank
                                        TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
                                        TextBox2.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
                                        TextBox1.SetFocus
                                        MsgBox "Please enter start date and beginning sequence number"
                                        Exit Sub
                            End If
                Else
                '####################################
                '##      START DATE is blank       ##
                '##  SEQUENCE filled in correctly  ##
                '####################################
                            'PROPNUM COLUMN populated
                            If TextBox8 = "" Then
                                        TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
                                        TextBox8.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
                                        TextBox1.SetFocus
                                        MsgBox "Please enter start date and propnum column"
                                        Exit Sub
                            Else
                                        TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
                                        TextBox1.SetFocus
                                        MsgBox "Please enter start date"
                                        Exit Sub
                            End If
                End If
    Else
    '####################################
    '## START DATE filled in correctly ##
    '####################################
                'SEQUENCE populated
                If TextBox2 = "" Then
                            'PROPNUM COLUMN populated
                            If TextBox8 = "" Then
                                        TextBox2.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
                                        TextBox8.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
                                        TextBox2.SetFocus
                                        MsgBox "Please enter beginning sequence and propnum column"
                                        Exit Sub
                            Else
                                        TextBox2.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
                                        TextBox2.SetFocus
                                        MsgBox "Please enter beginning sequence number"
                                        Exit Sub
                            End If
                Else
                '####################################
                '## START DATE filled in correctly ##
                '##  SEQUENCE filled in correctly  ##
                '####################################
                            'PROPNUM COLUMN populated
                            If TextBox8 = "" Then
                                        TextBox8.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
                                        TextBox8.SetFocus
                                        MsgBox "Please enter the propnum column"
                                        Exit Sub
                            End If
                End If
    End If

    'checks CheckBox's to see if they are checked (checked = 1, not checked = 0)
    For Each chk In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf chk Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
            If chk = 0 Then
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'if they were all 0 (not checked) this will be 13
    If i = 13 Then
        MsgBox "Please select at least one keyword category"
        Exit Sub
    End If



    'saves the selected number of keyword categories and start date
    Sheets("hidden").Visible = True
    Sheets("hidden").Select
    Sheets("hidden").Range("A2").Value = TextBox1.text
    Sheets("hidden").Range("B2").Value = TextBox2.text
    Sheets("hidden").Range("C2").Value = TextBox8.text



    'saves the CheckBox keywords
    For j = 1 To 13
        'what this box checked (1 is checked)
        m = 0
        If Me.Controls("CheckBox" & j) = 1 Then
            Sheets("hidden").Cells((3 + m), 1).Value = Me.Controls("CheckBox" & j).Caption
            m = m + 1
        End If
    Next j


    'i is the number of categories that were checked
    For c = 1 To 13
        'puts the variables into the spreadsheet
        With Me

                'once all checks are done clear out any previously saved KEYWORDS
                If c = 1 Then
                    k = 4
                    Sheets("hidden").Visible = True
                    Sheets("hidden").Select
                    Range(Cells(k, 1), Cells(k + 9, 3)).Select
                    Range(Cells(k, 1), Cells(k + 9, 3)).Clear
                    Sheets("hidden").Cells(4, 3).Value = Sheets("hidden").Cells(2, 2).Value
                Else
                End If
                'KEYWORDS and line continuations get saved
                If Me.Controls("CheckBox" & c).Object.Value = True Then
                    'If c = 1 Or c = 2 Then
                        Sheets("hidden").Cells(k, 1).Value = .Controls("CheckBox" & c).Caption
                        Sheets("hidden").Cells(k, 2).Value = .Controls("TextBox" & (k - 1)).text
                        Sheets("hidden").Cells((k + 1), 3).Value = Sheets("hidden").Cells(k, 2).Value + Sheets("hidden").Cells(k, 3).Value + 1
                    k = k + 1
                End If
        End With
    Next c

    'remove last KSS cell -- it isnt needed
    Cells(k, 3).Clear

    Unload Me

    Unload UserForm3
    UserForm3.Show

    Sheets("Imported Data").Select

End Sub
Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    'checks START DATE if there is something in it, if its blank skip check
    If TextBox1 <> "" Then
        'START DATE a date
        If Not IsDate(TextBox1) Then
            TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
            TextBox1.SetFocus
            MsgBox "Please enter start date in MM/YYYY format"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            If Not IsNumeric(Right(TextBox1.Value, 4)) Then
                TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
                TextBox1.SetFocus
                MsgBox "Please enter start date in MM/YYYY format"
                Exit Sub
            Else
                If Right(TextBox1.Value, 4) > 2050 Then
                    TextBox1.SetFocus
                    MsgBox "Are you sure about your date?"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    'changes color back to white for correct
    TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)


End Sub
Private Sub TextBox2_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    'checks SEQUENCE if there is something in it, if its blank skip check
    If TextBox2 <> "" Then
        'BEGINNING SEQUENCE a number and not blank
        If Not IsNumeric(TextBox2) Then
            TextBox2.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
            MsgBox "Please enter a numeric beginning sequence number"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'BEGINNING SEQUENCE a positive number
        If TextBox2 < 1 Then
            TextBox2.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
            MsgBox "Please enter a positive beginning sequence"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            'BEGINNING SEQUENCE trim decimals
            If TextBox2 > 0 And TextBox2 < 10 Then
                TextBox2.Value = Left(TextBox2, 1)
            Else
                TextBox2.Value = Left(TextBox2, 2)
            End If
        End If
    End If

    'changes color back to white for correct
    TextBox2.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)

End Sub
Private Sub TextBox8_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    'checks PROPNUM COLUMN if it is entered in correct format, if its blank skip check
    If TextBox8 <> "" Then
        'START DATE a date
        If IsNumeric(TextBox8) Then
            TextBox8.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
            MsgBox "Please enter propnum column in Y format"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    'changes color back to white for correct
    TextBox8.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)


End Sub
Private Sub TextBox3_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    'if the box is blank skip the check
    If TextBox3 <> "" Then
        'CONTINUATION LINE numeric
        If Not IsNumeric(TextBox3) Then
            TextBox3.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
            MsgBox "Please enter a number into the UNIQUE GAS continuation line box"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            'CONTINUATION LINE positive
            If TextBox3 < 0 Then
                TextBox3.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
                MsgBox "Please enter a positive number into the UNIQUE GAS continuation line box"
                Exit Sub
            Else
                'CONTINUATION LINE less than 6
                If TextBox3 > 5 Then
                    TextBox3.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
                    MsgBox "Plese enter a number less than 6 into the UNIQUE GAS continuation line box"
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    'CONTINUATION LINE whole number
                    TextBox3.Value = Left(TextBox3, 1)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    'CONTINUATION LINE box white for correct
    TextBox3.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)

End Sub
Private Sub TextBox4_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    'if the box is blank skip the check
    If TextBox4 <> "" Then
        'CONTINUATION LINE numeric
        If Not IsNumeric(TextBox4) Then
            TextBox4.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
            MsgBox "Please enter a number into the OIL continuation line box"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            'CONTINUATION LINE positive
            If TextBox4 < 0 Then
                TextBox4.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
                MsgBox "Please enter a positive number into the OIL continuation line box"
                Exit Sub
            Else
                'CONTINUATION LINE less than 6
                If TextBox4 > 5 Then
                    TextBox4.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
                    MsgBox "Plese enter a number less than 6 into the OIL continuation line box"
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    'CONTINUATION LINE whole number
                    TextBox4.Value = Left(TextBox4, 1)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    'CONTINUATION LINE box white for correct
    TextBox4.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)

End Sub
Private Sub TextBox5_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    'if the box is blank skip the check
    If TextBox5 <> "" Then
        'CONTINUATION LINE numeric
        If Not IsNumeric(TextBox5) Then
            TextBox5.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
            MsgBox "Please enter a number into the GAS continuation line box"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            'CONTINUATION LINE positive
            If TextBox5 < 0 Then
                TextBox5.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
                MsgBox "Please enter a positive number into the GAS continuation line box"
                Exit Sub
            Else
                'CONTINUATION LINE less than 6
                If TextBox5 > 5 Then
                    TextBox5.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
                    MsgBox "Plese enter a number less than 6 into the GAS continuation line box"
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    'CONTINUATION LINE whole number
                    TextBox5.Value = Left(TextBox5, 1)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    'CONTINUATION LINE box white for correct
    TextBox5.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)

End Sub
Private Sub TextBox6_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    'if the box is blank skip the check
    If TextBox6 <> "" Then
        'CONTINUATION LINE numeric
        If Not IsNumeric(TextBox6) Then
            TextBox6.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
            MsgBox "Please enter a number into the WATER continuation line box"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            'CONTINUATION LINE positive
            If TextBox6 < 0 Then
                TextBox6.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
                MsgBox "Please enter a positive number into the WATER continuation line box"
                Exit Sub
            Else
                'CONTINUATION LINE less than 6
                If TextBox6 > 5 Then
                    TextBox6.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
                    MsgBox "Plese enter a number less than 6 into the WATER continuation line box"
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    'CONTINUATION LINE whole number
                    TextBox6.Value = Left(TextBox6, 1)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    'CONTINUATION LINE box white for correct
    TextBox6.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)

End Sub
Private Sub TextBox7_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    'if the box is blank skip the check
    If TextBox7 <> "" Then
        'CONTINUATION LINE numeric
        If Not IsNumeric(TextBox7) Then
            TextBox7.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
            MsgBox "Please enter a number into the NGL continuation line box"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            'CONTINUATION LINE positive
            If TextBox7 < 0 Then
                TextBox7.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
                MsgBox "Please enter a positive number into the NGL continuation line box"
                Exit Sub
            Else
                'CONTINUATION LINE less than 6
                If TextBox7 > 5 Then
                    TextBox7.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 153)
                    MsgBox "Plese enter a number less than 6 into the NGL continuation line box"
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    'CONTINUATION LINE whole number
                    TextBox7.Value = Left(TextBox7, 1)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    'CONTINUATION LINE box white for correct
    TextBox7.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)

End Sub
```

Comment: Where & how are the forms being shown?

Comment: Mathieu sorry I cant see your link with my internet permissions.  To answer your question about where & how userforms are being shown.

On the main worksheet there is a button to start the process.  It brings up userform1, where some info is entered then either click cancel or OK.  OK goes to userform3 (2 got deleted and i never re-named them) and unloads and hides 1.

On uf3 when I click cancel it goes back to uf1.  When I click cancel on uf1 it unloads and closes and immediately re-opens?

I ended up re-making the userforms in a new workbook and copy paste all code.  It works now....?

Comment: ....Well I thought it was working but now my new workbook is doing the same thing!  I am guessing it has to do with something in userform1.  I will post entire code.